# ColdFusion - CFDOCUMENT Title in URL

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfdocument

I am creating a PDF document using ColdFusion `cfdocument` tag.  Works fine, however instead of showing the document name in browser Title - it shows the .cfc file that I call to create the PDF.

Here is how I'm calling it.

```
<cfdocument format="pdf" marginbottom=".5" margintop=".25" marginright=".5" marginleft=".5" saveAsName="#filename#.pdf">
     <cfdocumentitem type="footer">
          <p style="font-size:11px; text-align:right; font-style:italic;">Page #cfdocument.currentpagenumber# of #cfdocument.totalpagecount#</p>
     </cfdocumentitem>
     <html>
          <head><title>#filename#.pdf</title></head>
          <body><img src="file:///#application.tempFolder#\#thisFilename#" /></body>
     </html>
</cfdocument>
```

What the heck am I missing?  Why does it still show the filename.cfc file that I'm calling in the browser title instead of the filename I give to the PDF???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  Had to create the document using CFDOCUMENT, then add a "Title" attribute to it using the CFPDF tag.  Then output it to the browser.

```
<!--- Create the PDF --->
<cfdocument format="pdf" marginbottom=".5" margintop=".25" marginright=".5" marginleft=".5" filename="#application.tempFolder#\#thisSaveAsFilename#" overwrite="yes">
    <cfdocumentitem type="footer">
        <p style="font-size:11px; text-align:right; font-style:italic;">Page #cfdocument.currentpagenumber# of #cfdocument.totalpagecount#</p>
    </cfdocumentitem>
    <html>
        <head><title>#thisSaveAsFilename#</title></head>
        <body><img src="file:///#application.tempFolder#\#thisFilename#" /></body>
    </html>
</cfdocument>
<!--- Use CFPDF to add attributes to it --->
<cfset thisInfo = StructNew()>
<cfset thisInfo.Title = "pdf title goes here...">
<cfpdf action="setinfo" info="#thisInfo#" source="#application.tempFolder#\#thisSaveAsFilename#" />
<!--- Send it to the browser --->
<cfcontent file="#application.tempFolder#\#thisSaveAsFilename#" type="application/pdf" />A
```